# Load EhCache diskstore content into memory

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, memorycache

As said in [EhCache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/get-started/storage-options):

> In practice this means that persistent **in-memory cache will start up with all of its elements on disk**. [...] So, the Ehcache design does not load them all into memory on start up, but lazily loads them as required.

I would like that the memory cache start up will all its elements in memory, how can I achieve that?

The reason for this is that our website performs a *lot* of access to the cache, so the first time we visit the website it has very bad response time.

Comment: Can you iterate through all the entries on startup?

Comment: That's what I do currently, but the way that it's done is very slow (I call high level methods in loops, and those high level methods make DB requests too). If there was a way to iterate simply on all entries directly with EhCache API, that could be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that all the cached elements are in the DiskStore and you want them to be in-memory as soon as the application is started. In anycase  using BootStrapCacheLoader and BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory should be helpful.

I am just giving idea where we load DiskStore into memeory after the application is started

You can implement BootstrapCacheLoader which will load the cache elements as below. Definition of the method ***BootstrapCacheLoader.load(Ehcache cache)*** can be

```
       //CustomBootstrapCacheLoader implements BootstrapCacheLoader


        List<?> keys = cache.getKeys();

        if ((keys == null) || keys.isEmpty())
        {
            return;
        }

        for (Object key : keys)
        {
           Element el = cache.getQuiet(key);
           cache.removeQuiet(key);
           cache.putQuiet(el);
        }
```

Above method reads the element from DiskCache, Removes it and Puts it back so that it stays in the memory and disk version is removed.

Implement BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory so that

```
public class CustomBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory extends BootstrapCacheLoaderFactor
{
.
.
@Override
public BootstrapCacheLoader createBootstrapCacheLoader(Properties properties)
{
    CustomBootstrapCacheLoader loader = new CustomBootstrapCacheLoader();
    loader.setAsynchronous(getAsyncFromProperty(properties));

    return loader;
}
.
.
}
```

You can define cache configuration as below with CustomBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory  as below

```
<cache
         name="DummyCacheEl"
         maxElementsInMemory="3500"
         eternal="true"
         overflowToDisk="false"
         diskPersistent="true"
         memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
         <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="CustomBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"  properties="async=true"/>
</cache>
```

Comment: +1 for BootstrapCacheLoader. A small suggestion in your code on removing from disk and loading them in memory,

Element el = cache.removeAndReturnElement(key);

I would recommend this approach rather doing a get and then removing the element.

Comment: True, but it notifies CacheEventListener . May not be required when you are bootstrapping the cache.

Comment: Yeah, so in case if there are no notifier's configured for that cache then this will help in performance.

Comment: Yep. Moreover we have to load the cache asynchronously( spawn a thread in loadcache method) so that it is now blocking instance startup

Comment: `removes it and Puts it back so that it stays in the memory and disk version is removed.` I don't want to remove elements from the disk cache? I just want them to be loaded in memory.

Comment: Cool. **Element el = cache.getQuiet(key);** This statement alone should take care of that