# How to load diskStore cache into memory in ehcache

Tags: spring-mvc, caching, ehcache

I use ehcache in spring mvc. after server reset cache data save in diskStore. but after server starting not be use cache data. so I want to load diskstore content into memory.How do it? in this stackquestion [Load EhCache diskstore content into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448274/load-ehcache-diskstore-content-into-memory) use BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory but not appear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`BootstrapCacheLoader` concept](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration#cache-warming-for-multi-tier-caches) is a performance optimization for Ehcache.

It allows synchronous or asynchronous prefetch of entries, in different conditions.

In order to prefetch disk entries into memory, use the `DiskStoreBootstrapCacheLoader`. It will iterate over the keys known by the cache and load them up to the point the memory is filled as per the cache configuration.

But given that you mention your cache is not being used after restart, you probably have another issue that this technique will not help resolve.